# Check for the option label string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using the option Label string for my Html.DropDownList but my datasource is a SelectList. How I would check for the option label back on the server? The backing type for the variable is an EnumType. I inspected the value and it says 0 but it won't let me check for 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about casting the value back to the enum type on the server:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int selectedValue)
{
    MyEnum label = (MyEnum)selectedValue;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Labels aren't posted with the form.  You'll need to place the value in a `<input type="hidden">` if you want the value.